# What is $i^j$ for quaternions?

Tags: quaternions

Given complex numbers, we can calculate e.g. $i^i$.

Given quaternions, how can we calculate something like $i^j$? Wolfram Mathematica choked on that and googling did not produce any useful results. My guess is that this could be something ill defined, similar to quaternion derivative or, perhaps, even worse.

Comment: You'll probably need a good look at what the exponential map does in quaternion-land. Similarly to matrices, start with its power series and look at what the extension does. Actually, pass through to one of the 4x4 representations and look at its matrix exponential.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1204775/11619). See also other threads linked to that one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - the answer by md2perpe is simple, precise, and surprisingly exact in comparison to the discussion in the "related" answer. The comments by RobertLewis are also great as they show that $i^i$ is not well defined. It is then interesting that $i^j$ is well defined under some very reasonable assumptions.

Comment: Konstantin, md2perpe even refused to give a precise definition of a quaternion power. I agree that we can define $e^q$, but the same ambiguity is present. Admittedly there is the surprise that for this power the phase ambiguity disappears (that is a bonus). So I did not downvote their answer.

Comment: Anyway, the whole concept of quaternion power is fuzzy. md2perpe apparently defines $q_1^{q_2}$ as follows. Write $q_1=a+b\vec{u}$ for some unit vector $\vec{u}$. Then we can write $q_1=e^{\ell}$ where $\ell=\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\vec{u}\phi$, where $\phi$ is the phase of the 2D point $(a,b)$. So far so good (apart from the multiple of $2\pi$ ambiguity). But, can we really define $q_1^{q_2}:=e^{\ell q_2}$? Why not $q_1^{q_2}:=e^{q_2\ell}$? That would also extend the complex power. What criteria are we using to call this definition the correct one?

Comment: Observe that, unlike in the complex case,  we may have $e^{q_1+q_2}\neq e^{q_1}\cdot e^{q_2}$. What are the justifications for the particular choices made?

Comment: Sorry about the missing parens in $\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$. Of course, $a,b$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
i^j 
= (e^{i\pi/2})^j
= e^{ij\pi/2}
= e^{k\pi/2}
= k
$$

Comment: Nice, nobody needs to figure out how cross-terms work

Comment: The second equation in particular looks like a huge leap of faith. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Are you referring to $(e^{i\pi/2})^j = e^{ij\pi/2}$?

Comment: Yes. A) What's your definition of quaternion power/exponential? B) Why does the law $(e^{q_1})^{q_2}=e^{q_1q_2}$ hold? I know that we can define $e^q$ with the usual power series, but you seem to be using something more general.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. For complex numbers, $z,w,$ the power is defined by
$$z^w = (e^{\ln|z|+i\arg z})^w = e^{(\ln|z|+i\arg z)w}.$$
Therefore I assumed the analog definition of power of quaternions.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704533/11619) for more of what goes wrong if you do this.

Comment: I never claimed that the result is unique.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen strangelly, I get $\cosh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\pm k \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

Comment: @Anixx. Could you show your calculation?

Comment: I am using this code for Mathematica: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4568761/2513

Comment: @Anixx. I'm not good at Mathematica, but I think that I can understand the code. I don't understand however how that code defines and calculates $i^j$ (a matrix to a matrix power).

Comment: @md2perpe I have updated the code a bit

Comment: @Anixx. I still don't understand how it defines and calculates and matrix to a matrix power.

Comment: You are right, the code was wrong. Now it gives exactly your result.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to this, but there is one thing I'm not seeing in the other responses. For some reason
$$ i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i+2\pi ni }, n\in\mathbb{Z} $$
but since we're dealing with quaternions, it shouldn't be unreasonable to say that
$$ i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i + 2 \pi x i + 2 \pi y j + 2 \pi z k }, \text{ for } x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}\\ \text{since }  e^{2 \pi x i} = e^{2 \pi y j} = e^{2 \pi z k} =  1 $$
In this case
$$ i^{j} = (e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i + 2 \pi x i + 2 \pi y j + 2 \pi z k })^{j}\\
= e^{\frac{\pi}{2} ij + 2 \pi x ij + 2 \pi y jj + 2 \pi z kj }\\
= e^{\frac{\pi}{2} k + 2 \pi x k - 2 \pi y - 2 \pi z i }\\
= e^{\frac{\pi}{2} k} e^{ 2 \pi x k} e^{ - 2 \pi y} e^{ - 2 \pi z i }\\
= k \cdot 1 \cdot e^{ - 2 \pi y} \cdot 1\\ 
= e^{ - 2 \pi y} k$$
which is not well-defined since the choice for $y$ (and less importantly $x$ and $z$) is arbitrary.

Note that even with all of this, it shouldn't work out so nicely in general due to quaternions not being commutative as $(q_{1}q_{2})^{n}\neq q_{1}^{n} q_{2}^{n}$ unless $q_{1}q_{2} = q_{2}q_{1}$, but a lot of the cases here are ultimately multiplying things by 1 (or some other real number), which might commute well, but I'm unsure.

Similarly, the order of addition of exponents isn't changed so that it can be used more as shorthand since $e^{q_{1}+q_{2}}$ isn't exactly well-defined as $e^{q_{1}}e^{q_{2}}\neq e^{q_{2}}e^{q_{1}}$ in general.

A little bit of a tangent, but another property that may not necessarily hold, especially if the previous line did without additive commutativity in the exponent (except where $e^{q}=1$) is that $e^{q_{1}}=e^{q_{2}}\Rightarrow q_{1} = q_{2}$. Assuming it did hold, then using $i$ as above and a similar $j$ and $k$, you could show that $ij=k \Rightarrow k = ni + mj \text{ for some } n,m\in\mathbb{Q}$, which is clearly false.

Answer (score 0):

How do we meaningfully calculate $i^i$?  One way which comes to mind is to write

$i = e^{\pi i \ 2}, \tag 1$

and thus

$i^i = (e^{\pi i / 2})^i; \tag 2$

if we now *assume* the rule

$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}, \; a, b, c \in \Bbb C, \tag 3$

is valid, then (2) becomes

$i^i = (e^{\pi i / 2})^i = e^{\pi i^2 / 2} = e^{-\pi / 2}. \tag 4$

So far, so good; however, the equation (1) does *not* uniquely define $i$ as an exponential; indeed, we have

$i = e^{(2n + 1/ 2)\pi i}, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag 5$

whence

$i^i = (e^{(2n + 1/2)\pi i})^i = e^{(2n + 1/2)\pi i^2} = e^{-(2n + 1/2)\pi}, n \in \Bbb Z. \tag 6$

If we accept these results, we may move on to attempting to calculate $i^j$; from (5), assuming (3) holds for quaternions,

$i^j = (e^{(2n + 1/2)\pi i})^j = e^{(2n + 1/2)\pi ij} = e^{(2n + 1/2)\pi k}$
$= e^{2n\pi k} e^{\pi k / 2} = e^{\pi k / 2} = k, \; n \in \Bbb Z. \tag 7$

It is perhaps worth noting that

$i^j = k = ij, \tag 8$

and that *via* cyclic permutation $i \to j \to k$ we find

$j^k = i = jk, \tag 9$

and

$k^i = j = ki. \tag{10}$

***Note Added in Edit, Friday 19 June 2020 12:51 PM PST:***  A few words in response to the comment of Konstantin Konstantinov on this answer.  The defining relations of the quaternion algebra,

$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1, \tag{11}$

$ij = k, jk = i, ki = j, \tag{12}$

found in [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), lead naturally to the formulas

$e^{2n\pi i} = e^{2n \pi j} = e^{2n\pi k} = 1, n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{13}$

from which we see that for

$t \in [0, 2\pi) \tag{14}$

$e^{(2n\pi + t)i} = e^{2n\pi i}e^{t\pi i} = e^{t\pi i}, n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{15}$

and corresponding formulas with $j$ and $k$ replacing $i$.  From this we see that there are a countably infinite number of distinct solutions to (15), ***viz.***

$2n\pi + t, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{16}$

with corresponding solution sets for the $j$ and $k$ variants of (15).  We further observe that

$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta, \tag{17}$

again with the corresponding relations for $j$ and $k$; of course (17) gives rise to (5) in the usual manner:

$e^{(2n + 1/ 2)\pi i} = \cos ((2n + 1/2)\pi) + i \sin ((2n + 1/2)\pi)$
$= i\sin((2n + 1/2)\pi) = i\sin((1/2) \pi) = i, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag{18}$

and again, the corresponding statements hold for $j$ and $k$.
***End of Note.***

Comment: It is then interesting that  it is branch cut discontinuity of $log$ on a complex plane that results in that ambiguity of $i^i$, whereas for quaternions the value of $i^j$ is well defined and does not have such a discontinuity.

Comment: I know nothing about quaternions. Is the rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ rather than $(a^b)^c=a^{cb}$ based on anything more principled than the notational happenstance that exponents are placed on the right of the base rather than on the left or directly above?

Comment: In addition to the criticism from @bof I want to point out that in general the rule $e^{q_1+q_2}=e^{q_1}\cdot e^{q_2}$ is only valid when $q_1q_2=q_2q_1$. In the cases where you apply it that holds. But the whole concept is just very fuzzy.